# How many four-digit numbers are there formed from the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (with possible repetition) that are evenly divisible by 4?

Tags: combinatorics

I am stuck on this problem.

I started to solve the problem by finding the set of all possible numbers that can be formed without concern about divisibility by $4$, that is

$5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 = 5^{4}$

since if it divisible by $4$, it must be even number I must find the set of odd numbers that end with $1,3,5$ and exclude it from the main set, 
that is

$5^{3}+5^{3}+5^{3}$

but I got stuck at the set that ends with $2,4$ since it is not guaranteed that those numbers must be divisible by $4$.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number is divisible by four if its last two digits are divisible by four. The set of possible answers is:

1. **12
2. **24
3. **32
4. **44
5. **52

Where * is any of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. There are $5\cdot 5 = 25$ permutation options for each **. Thus there are $25 \times 5 = 125$ numbers divisible by four from the digits $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: It would be better to say that a number is divisible by $4$ if the number formed by its last two digits is divisible by $4$.  Also, if repetition is allowed, each of the first two digits can be filled in five ways.

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig for the corrected solution where there are 25 permutations (with repetition allowed) for the first two digits **, not 20.

Comment: You should edit your answer to make that change rather than leaving it in the comments where future readers might miss it.

Answer (score 2):

The number formed by last two digits must be divisible by 4, to make the number divisible by 4.
Therefore the four digit number that can be formed are

_ _ $12$
_ _ $24$
_ _ $32$
_ _ $52$
_ _ $44$

You need to fill the spaces with five digits. 
So for first combination there are $5 \cdot 5$ ways. 
For five combinations there are $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5$ ways.

Comment: Since repetition of digits is permitted, you should also consider numbers whose last two digits are $44$.